# Inserting Static Block in Sidebar

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block

I am trying to create my own navigation bars by creating the link in a static block then inserting the block into the left sidebar.
You can see one of my pages here: <strike>http://hi-schoolworld.com/pharmacy</strike>
The problem seems to be with the code in my local.xml file.
If I have this tag: 
then nothing shows up but if I comment it out then the block displays twice...
I can't think of anywhere else I would have referenced the block.
I've uploaded a screenshot of what I'm talking about here: <strike>http://hi-schoolworld.com/example.jpg</strike>

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: could you post your entire local.xml please

Comment: Too long to post the whole thing here...what other files could I look in? Is it possible that the block is rendering because of local.xml then again because of a different file like page.xml or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how proper of an answer this is but here's the solution:
I left  in the local.xml file and changed all pages' Layout Update XML to reference  (left.nav.menu) isn't listed in any .xml files as far as I can tell) and it works! The block is only displayed once.

Answer (score 6):

create local.xml at `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtemplate/layout/`

then you need call cms block from  using xml

```
<default>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="cms/block" name="somenameofcmsblok" >
            <!--
                The content of this block is taken from the database by its block_id.
                You can manage it in admin CMS -> Static Blocks
            -->
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>youblockcode</block_id></action>
        </block>
     </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: That would work if I wanted to use the same block site-wide but I want to use different blocks for each page...

Comment: I am using this code in the Layout Update XML section of each page:
<reference name="left">
<block type="cms/block" name="left.permanent.callout">
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>customNavBlock</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>

Comment: Can I comment out left.permanent.callout tag and add a tag with a different name? If so...what code is needed? I'm thinking I could call the block in the Layout Update XML something else...like:
<reference name="left"> <block type="cms/block" name="something.else">

Comment: yes,use different name

Comment: OK I went into catalog.xml and created this "<block type="core/template" name="left.nav.menu" template="callouts/left_col.phtml"></block>" then changed the name in my Layout Update XML to be left.nav.menu instead of left.permanent.callout and same problem....it must be rendering the block twice elsewhere...I'll keep searching

Comment: Crazy and I don't understand how this works but....
I deleted the new line I just created naming the left.nav.menu block in catalog.xml and now it's somehow working? The pages using the left.permanent.callout are still showing the block twice but the page using the left.nav.menu (which doesn't even exist in catalog.xml anymore) is displaying the block properly (once). - I'm a bit worried this is a delayed reaction from a previous change to a different file. I'm going to flush my cache and see if it stays this way. OK everything is flushed & I double-checked in a different browser and success!